# sumproduct and vlookup returning an error

Tags: excel, sum, excel-2007, vlookup

I have a function that reads:

`=SUMPRODUCT(VLOOKUP(D261, '[IJM current plan.xls]LO calcs'!$AU$12:$BO$147,{2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21},FALSE)+VLOOKUP(D261,'[IJM current plan.xls]OF calcs'!$BC$12:$CA$147,{2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25},FALSE))`

But this returns an error.

The aim is to add up the rows between **AU12** and **BO12** in the **LO calcs** tab as well as the rows between **BC12** and **CA12** in the **OF calcs** tab if the row contains the value in cell D261 (a date).

This returns an **#N/A** error and I'm not sure why, as this exact same method works for two other spreadsheets but not for **IJM current plan**.

I have checked that the names, file paths, rows and columns are correct, and that any hidden rows, columns or tabs are clearly visible.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this one:

```
=IFERROR(SUM(INDEX('[IJM current plan.xls]LO calcs'!$AV$12:$BO$147,
             MATCH(D261,'[IJM current plan.xls]LO calcs'!$AU$12:$AU$147,0),0)),0)
+IFERROR(SUM(INDEX('[IJM current plan.xls]OF calcs'!$BD$12:$CA$147,
             MATCH(D261,'[IJM current plan.xls]OF calcs'!$BC$12:$BC$147,0),0)),0)
```

Comment: Hi, thank you. This gets rid of the error, but returns the wrong numerical answer. It returns "0" when it should return "318". Any thoughts on this matter?

Comment: Just missed one thing. Updated my answer. Try now please